# Proving $\lim_{t\to \infty} t\mu(\{x:f(x)\geq t\})=0$ for $f \in L^1(\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I don't understand the solution our TA posted, and since I'm reviewing for the qual, I figured I'd ask here:

By Chebyshev's Inequality, $\limsup_t \mu(\{x:f(x)\geq t\}) \leq \lim_t \frac{\|f\|_{L^1}}{t} = 0$. So by dominated convergence theorem:

$$\limsup_t  t\mu(\{x:f(x)\geq t\}) \leq \lim_t \int_{|f|\geq t} |f| d\mu = 0$$

I understand the first part of Chebyshev's inequality. I don't understand how they derived the inequality $\limsup_t  t\mu(\{x:f(x)\geq t\}) \leq \lim_t \int_{|f|\geq t} |f| d\mu$ and where using LDCT is factoring in. There seems to be some steps missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that

$$t \mu\{f \ge t\} \le \int_{\{|f| \ge t\}} |f| \, d\mu \quad\quad (*)$$

just follows from the pointwise estimate of the integral on the right: The integrand is at least $t$, so

$$\int_{\{|f| \ge t\}} |f| \, d\mu \ge t \int_{\{|f| \ge t\}} \, d\mu$$

Now take $\limsup$ in $(*)$ and notice that the right hand side is increasing, so it can be replaced by $\lim$.

The dominated convergence theorem is what implies that the right hand side of $(*)$ tends to zero; if you think of it as

$$\int_X |f| \chi_{\{|f| \ge t\}} \, d\mu$$

instead, with $\chi$ being an indicator function, then the integrand tends to zero pointwise a.e.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you!